# Why does Hibernate detect child entities?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, entity, cascade

I have Parent entity and child entities,
and I gave CascadeType.PERSIT to child entities.

When I persist Parent with children, it works well.
But when I did add child, hibernate started to insert the row.

```
@Entity
class Parent{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
class Child{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne..
}


public void testCascade(){
    Parent parent = new Parent();

    Child child1 = new Child();
    Child child2 = new Child();

    parent.addChild(child1);
    parent.addChild(child2);

    em.persist(parent);

    // works well until here

    Child child3 = new Child();
    parent.addChild(child3);
}
```

When I add `child3` to `parent` without `em.persist`, they do `insert` child3 also.
Why they do this?
I knew `CascadeType.PERSIST` means like following.

```
em.persist(parent); 
==
em.persist(parent);
em.persist(child1);
em.persist(child2);
```

also `CascadeType.MERGE` means

```
em.merge(parent); 
==
em.merge(parent);
em.merge(child1);
em.merge(child2);
```

I didn't expect detection changes.
If I give `CascadeType.MERGE` it works well as I expected.

Can you explain this situation?

Comment: Not sure I follow, but `em.persist(parent)` makes the `parent` entity tracked, meaning that from now on, all changes to it are tracked and persisted to the data store. What behavior did you expect instead?

Comment: I expected that insert query was sent when `em.persist` executed. But it was my misunderstand because of the way of insert `@GeneratedValue`. Now I can figured out that code. Thank you